# Continuous and Differentiable function with discontinuous derivatives

Tags: calculus

Is it possible for a function to be continuous and differentiable in an interval, but its derivative over that interval is not continuous?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, 
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases} 
x^2\sin(1/x),&x\ne 0\\
0,&x=0
\end{cases}
$$
is the classic example.